# Showing hidden element on hover for only one row of the table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've  been trying to solve this for the last hour but unsuccessfully. Maybe some of you could help.

All I want to do is make glyphicon visible on table row hover but only for that particular hovered row. All it does now is hovering on any row will make all of hidden glyphicons visible.

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32386/) to recreate the problem but somehow it doesn't work like it should, but you should get the point.

I've tried using `:first-child` for almost everything but that doesn't seem to help.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".table-hover tbody tr td").hover(function() {
        $(".glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-right:first-child").css("visibility", "visible");
    },
    function () {
        $(".glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-right:first-child").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pull-left"></span><span class="label label-info">bla bla</span>SOME TEXT HERE</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pull-left"></span><span class="label label-info">bla bla</span>SOME TEXT HERE</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pull-left"></span><span class="label label-info">bla bla</span>SOME TEXT HERE</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-right {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -4px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.table a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00b6ff;
}
.table a:hover {
  padding-left: -10px;
}
.table-hover tbody tr td, .table-hover tbody tr th {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

Comment: Why would you not use CSS for this? `.glyphicon { visibility: hidden; } tr:hover .glyphicon { visibility: visible; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `:first-child`, use jQuery's `find()` like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table-hover tbody tr td").hover(function() {
      $(this).find(".glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-right").css("visibility", "visible");
    },
    function() {
      $(".glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-right").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */


body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.label.label-info {
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-right {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -4px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.table a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00b6ff;
}

.table-hover tbody tr td,
.table-hover tbody tr th {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right pull-left"></span><span class="label label-info" style="margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"></span>hhhhhh</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right pull-left"></span><span class="label label-info">Registracija atidaryta!</span>2017.09.01 Rudens pradžios anglų kalbos kursai. Plačiau...</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right pull-left"></span>2017.09.01 Rudens pradžios anglų kalbos kursai. Plačiau...</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right pull-left"></span>2017.09.01 Rudens pradžios anglų kalbos kursai. Plačiau...</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right pull-left"></span>2017.09.01 Rudens pradžios anglų kalbos kursai. Plačiau...</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks alot! but can you elaborate for my future use, how come find() made it look like this?

Comment: @PovilasSamitovas In this case, `find()` gets only the elements that are children of `$(this)` (the element that triggered the hover event)